# Find the first element in a list that verify a condition

Tags: kotlin

Assuming we are given a list of integers `R = [3,5,3,6,0,6,7]`, an threshold `x` (integer) and a window size (integer) `p`. For example, x=4 and p = 2.

I need to find the first index `t` that verifies the the following conditions:

- `R[t] >= 4, R[t+1] >= 4`. Since p=2, we need to only verify for two boxes `t` and `t+1`. If `p` was equal to `3` we will need to verify for `t`, `t+1` and `t+2`.

Here the `t` I am looking for is `5` (indexing is starting from 0).

How to write this in a elegant way in Kotlin (rather than looping on the elements).

A tentative that is giving an error (x=4 and p = 2. The output should be 3 since we start indexing by 0):

```kotlin
val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2)
val firstIndex = numbers.find { it >= 4 for it in it..it+2-1}
```

Comment: `it` in your code there is the value of something in the list, not the index of that value, but you're using it as both.

Answer (score 5):

```kotlin
val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2)
val p = 2
val x = 4

val t = numbers.windowed(p).indexOfFirst { window -> window.all { it >= x } } // t == 3
```

`t` will be equal to `-1` in case if no matches will be found

Comment: `indexOfFirst`, nice.

Answer (score 3):

[find](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/find.html) Returns the first element matching the given predicate, or null if no such element was found.

Comment: Yup, but struggling to write that predicate :/ I don't know how to very a condition (greater than x) starting from t and for the next p

Answer (score 2):

Use `windowed` to check groups of values for each index in the list. Use `withIndex()` so you are iterating with the indices, which you need in your final result. Then use `firstOrNull()` (which `find()` is a redundant alias of). And finally, take `?.index` to get the index of the first entry that satisfies the condition, or null if none satisfy.

```
    val x = 4
    val p = 3
    val list = listOf(2,5,3,6,0,6,7)
    val t = list
        .windowed(p)
        .withIndex()
        .firstOrNull { (_, sublist) -> sublist.all { it >= x } }
        ?.index
```

Comment: See the other answer. `indexOfFirst` is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, this should work:

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(3,5,3,6,0,6,7)
    val p = 2
    val x = 4

    val t = list.withIndex().windowed(p).firstOrNull() { window ->
        window.all { it.value >= x }
    }?.first()?.index

    println(t)
}
```

Output:

```
5
```